# How to set up Keil Logic Analyzer to read specific pin?

Tags: microcontroller, arm, keil, logic-analyzer, arm7

How can I set the Keil uVision 5 Logic Analyzer so that I can read the status of a specific pin, example high or low?

I have read the official docs [here](http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/uv4/uv4_db_dbg_logicanalyzer_setup.htm), however it does not say anything of the sort. I know it can be done as I had seen a demonstration which ustilised this useful function, but can't remember how.

Let us say I want to monitor pin 10 on port 0. I have tried many variations such as:

`PINSEL0<<10`
`0<<10`
`P0.10`
, however I keep getting the same error message below. Any help on how this can be done?

[image]

Comment: It should just be `PINSEL0`, and then you use the And Mask and Shift Right fields to get what you want. I'm not posting this as an answer because I don't have Keil to verify.

Comment: Thanks for you input on this matter. Luckily just found out how, will post below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following worked for me:

**(port0 & 0x00000400) >> 10**

This specifies an AND mask for the signal value on port 0, while shifting by 10.

Important to set the Logic Analyzer functionality as `bit` and not `analogue`.

---

Even easier is:

**port0.10**

Answer (score -1):

Try with:

**FIO0PIN.10**

this one works for me.